# Detecting items with tags

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried many commands and this is what I came up with but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have a suggestion for a fix?

`/tag @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",Count:1b,Slot:102b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Heavy Vest\"}"},Tags:["HeavyVest"]}}]}] add HeavyVest`

If I remove the `Tags:["HeavyVest"]`, it works, but I want to be able to test for items with tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to tag an entity, but items in the inventory are not entities.  Try this command:

/tag @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",Count:1b,Slot:102b,tag:{display:{Name:"\"Heavy Vest\""}}}]}] add HeavyVest